# Bind buttons to array with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an array of buttons that are generated with the `*ngFor`. It's a two day array. It generates rows based on one array and columns based on another. So one array is x = {a,b,c} and another is y = {0,1,2,3,4,5}. so I have 3 rows of 5 buttons. I want to bind each button to a spot in array to hold the toggled value. So A,3 should be the 3rd place, and c5 should be the 18th place in the array. I have i and j tracking each position for each array.

I tried binding it like `[(ngModel)]="ary[i*y.length+j]"` but it's ungodly slow and should be almost instant. This doesn't work and throw the error `no value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

Has anyone had any experience with binding things generated with a *ngFor to a spot in an array?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment as it isn't really an answer, but try switching to reactive forms. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: Can you build a plunker to demonstrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would but it's a ton of work for an angular app. Let's see what I can do. I might've solved the issue, but I'm still verifying it

Comment: Creating the plunker is a simple two step process: (1) Open a plunker editor. (2) Select New and then Angular from the drop down list. You then have a working Angular app that you can edit for your needs.